# Laravel - Inertia - Vue: Data will not response correct

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a Vue layout component in which I implement several other Vue components. Among other things also the header. In the header I implement another component called Notification.

I want that when rendering from my header, a get request is made to a specific route and the controller returns data & stores it in the props.notificationdata.

The problem I am having is that I am not getting the data back.

1. with a simple `return $data` it is not inertia compliant.
2. returning a rendering is also not possible, because it is not a main component that is rendered directly otherwise.
3. according to the Laravel docs simply a `return back()->with();`.

Unfortunately I can't find the correct solution....

Here is my Request:

```
let props = defineProps({
    notificationdata: Object,
});

function GetNotificationData() {
    props.notificationdata = Inertia.get('/account/user/notifications',
        { preserveState: false, preserveScroll: true }
    );
}
```

Here is the php Function:

```
static function getUserNotifications() {
    $query = Notification::query();
    $query->where('state', 0);
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    $data = $query->get();

    return back()->with(['notificationdata' => $data]);
}
```

Comment: What gives the response back ?

Comment: There was no response. I have now solved the problem with axios, since a simple XHR request is not possible using Inertia. Thanks anyway!